# SSCollectionView Delete Section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sstoolkit

I'm deleting a section in `SSCollectionView` as follows:

```
[self.collectionView beginUpdates];
[self.collectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withItemAnimation:SSCollectionViewItemAnimationFade];
[self.collectionView endUpdates];
```

That's exactly as described by its docs. I'm getting the following error however:

`*** Assertion failure in -[SSCollectionViewTableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:1054`

What is wrong with what I'm doing? That's pretty much how the being update and end update block works with `UITableView`s and other view controllers in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

In your error log: It does mention a `UITableView`. Maybe you have your classes mixed up? Check that everything is alright with your parent classes and that you have assigned the correct class in Interface Builder.